# Using Angular what would be the best way to store whether a user has previously checked a checkbox and then recall it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a bit of a novice who is the process of learning angular whilst developing a web application. This application is similar to a todo list (football team checklist), where a user would go through a menu by firstly selecting a league (there are 4), then the application would take the ID of that selection and load the next page by making a http request for a JSON file depending on the ID of the selection (hope that makes sense). The next page is then where the checkboxes are which contain a list of teams from that league and the user would simply check off all the football grounds they have visited in that football season.

It all works fine, however how would I store whether the user as checked off a team using localStorage and then retrieve this on page load?

I initially used a ng-change() method, however this called the same teams for every league, because I was calling the same data from localStorage instead of the JSON file depending on ID, which made sense after I had done it.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML that contains the teams and checklists:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="club in league" ng-click="selectClub(club.id)">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="club.done">
    <a href="#/team">{{club.club}} - {{club.ground}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller that gets the league ID and loads the data:

```
trackerControllers.controller('ClubCtrl',  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var leagueId=sessionStorage.getItem("leagueId");
    $http.get('JSON/Leagues/league'+leagueId+'.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.league = data;
    });
}]);
```

If there is anything I can do to make this question clearer then please suggest. Thanks!

To give a better idea of the site, here is the link to the new one - http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1170593/MyApp/index.html#/league

And a link to the old one that stored - http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1170593/version1/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for changes on each club's checkbox.  Update localStorage whenever the input changes.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="club in league" ng-click="selectClub(club.id)">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="club.done" ng-change="updateClub(club)">
    <a href="#/team">{{club.club}} - {{club.ground}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

$scope.updateClub = function (club) {
    var key = 'clubId-' + club.id;
    if (club.done) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, 'viewed');
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
};
```

Then when you load data check if each club has been viewed.

```
trackerControllers.controller('ClubCtrl',  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var leagueId=sessionStorage.getItem("leagueId");
    $http.get('JSON/Leagues/league'+leagueId+'.json').success(function(data) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // check if this team has been viewed
            data[i].done = localStorage.getItem('clubId-' + data[i].id) === 'viewed';
        }
        $scope.league = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: To clarify, the user would check the team as viewed and you would save that in local storage?

Comment: Hi Jon, what you suggested above worked! I glanced at the initial answer and misunderstood your response, apologies for that. Now I've sat down at my laptop and read through it, it makes sense, Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

> the application would take the ID of that selection and load the next
>   page by making a http request for a JSON file

The beauty of Angular is that you actually do not load a next page, like a conventional website would do. But instead it will render different templates/views on the "same url" based on your user interaction.

Because of this you do not need to 'pass' the variable, but just store it. e.a:

On user interaction:

```
$scope.leagueId = 1;
```

Since the scope is passed to the controller. You can just call the LeagueId from within the scope.

```
$http.get('JSON/Leagues/league'+$scope.leagueId+'.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.league = data;
});
```

Furthermore, I would advise to use some kind of db to store your data in and use a query to feed back the correct data based on the input parameter. And make calls to your data from a service or factory, rather then from the controller.

---

Edit:

I re-read the question and assume you would like to save the user input (indefinitely?).

In this case u definitely will need some kind of db-storage and sign-in functionality. Because u need to know which user u are dealing with.
So u will need a user-table and a table that defines which user has performed which actions.

Preferably:

- User table to store users and passwords (for login)
- Action table that defines what actions users can perform.
- User-Action table that stores which user have performed which actions.

The $scope won't work because it will terminate as soon as the user closes the browser. Storing it in the session won't work, because as soon as the session expires, your user input will be lost. And using cookies won't work either because, like the session, will keep track of the data per computer. So if your user uses another computer, the data will not be available.

Comment: Thanks for your help! To be honest, I'm not that bothered about indefinitely, localStorage will be enough because i'm naively going to assume every user will use their smartphone to access this site, and the only time the data will be lost is if the phone is wiped or when they change phones which isn't that often. Thanks again though.